# Vue2 - why does store.commit change payload from string to object

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to Vue and working my way through it.

I have this method

```
            itemClick() {
                let item = this.name;
                console.log( item );
                store.commit( 'updateSelectedItems', item );
            },
```

and this mutation

```
        updateSelectedItems( items ) {
            console.log( items );

            store.state.selectedItems.splice( 0 );
            store.state.selectedItems.push( items );
        }
```

The method console.log outputs the name correctly (it's coming from props). However, from the updateSelectedItems mutation log it outputs this an object containing all of my states.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because mutations are given the state as their first argument. The payload should then be put as a second parameter in the mutation's declaration (like so: `updateSelectedItems(state, item)`).

(See the docs for more details: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)

Comment: Ah of course! I have looked at that so many times, but failed to realize.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!